# Getting aggregate data in MySql

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to write a sql query to fetch aggregate data from a table. I have a table with data that looks as follows (example data):

| trackingId | numberOfRecords | totalRecords | dateSubmitted | fileName | checkpoint | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 01/01/2021 | example.doc | gateway | in-progress |
| 1 | 20 | 100 | 02/01/2021 | null | checkpoint1 | in-progress |
| 1 | 20 | 100 | 03/01/2021 | null | checkpoint2 | in-progress |

The aggregate data I would like to query would look like:

| trackingId | numberOfRecords | totalRecords | dateSubmitted | fileName | checkpoint | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 03/01/2021 | example.doc | checkpoint2 | in-progress |

In summary, I would like to:

- group on trackingId (done)
- Sum of all records fetched (done)
- get the latest date (done)
- name of original document (not sure how to fetch a value from the first row only, I am trying to avoid subqueries due to inefficiencies)
- latest checkpoint (get value from the newest record)
- latest status (get value from the newest record)

My issue mainly is fetching specific data from either the newest or oldest record.

Thanks.

Comment: look on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27465/fetch-the-newest-row-grouped-by-a-column-in-mysql

Comment: There's no date here

Comment: MySQL or BigQuery? please select one. For MySQL - specify precise version.

Comment: *name of original document (not sure how to fetch a value from the first row only, I am trying to avoid subqueries due to inefficiencies)* You need the value from the 1st roww even if the next row(s) is not NULL?

Comment: Yes, always the first row for the file name as we do not get the filename other checkpoints.

Comment: You could do a subquery that has ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select trackingId,
  sum(numberOfRecords) as numberOfRecords,
  any_value(totalRecords) as totalRecords,
  max(dateSubmitted) as dateSubmitted,
  array_agg(fileName order by dateSubmitted limit 1)[offset(0)] as fileName,
  array_agg(checkpoint order by dateSubmitted desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as checkpoint,
  array_agg(status order by dateSubmitted desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as status,
from `project.dataset.table`
group by trackingId
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look for this:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test ( id INT,    -- will be used for ordering
>                     cat INT,   -- will be used for aggregation
>                     col1 INT,  -- will be used for to get SUM
>                     col2 INT,  -- will be used for to get value from 1st row
>                     col3 INT   -- will be used for to get value from last row
>                     );
>                     
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> (1,1,11,111,1111), (2,1,22,222,2222), (3,1,33,333,3333),
> (4,2,4,4,4), (5,2,5,5,5);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | cat | col1 | col2 | col3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 11 | 111 | 1111 |
> | 2 | 1 | 22 | 222 | 2222 |
> | 3 | 1 | 33 | 333 | 3333 |
> | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
> | 5 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 5 |

> ```
> SELECT cat,
>        SUM(col1) col1_sum,
>        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(col2 ORDER BY id), ',', 1) col2_first,
>        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(col3 ORDER BY id), ',', -1) col3_last
> FROM test
> GROUP BY cat;
> ```
>
> | cat | col1_sum | col2_first | col3_last |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 66 | 111 | 3333 |
> | 2 | 9 | 4 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=0dbc5e4b975fba37cec48b085a28c50c)*

The values processed by GROUP_CONCAT() must **have no** comma in the value.

PS. Do not forget about [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len), especially when single value in the column may be long.

PPS. The expression for last value may be `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(col3 ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) col3_last`.